# login page submit button works after second attempt with filling form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, authentication

I have entered the correct username and password but my login page does not respond to the first attempt: it does respond though on th second attempt.

My login page is **login.php** and landing page is **index.php**

Here is my html:

```
<form  method="post" >
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required />
 <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
<button class="btn btn-default submit"  >Log In</button>
</form>
```

Here is my php code

```
if($_POST){
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$select="select * from user_registration where email='$email' and password='$password'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$select);
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

if($data['email']!=$email or $data['password']!=$password or $data['status']=='Pending')
{
  echo "Invalid username or password";  
  header("location:login.php");

}
elseif($data['email']==$email and $data['password']==$password)
{

  $_SESSION['name']=$email; 
  $_SESSION['user_name']=$data['user_name'];  
  $_SESSION['user_id']=$data['id']; 
  header("location:index.php");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one.

Your HTML code :

```
<form  method="post" >
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-default submit"  >Log In</button>
</form>
```

And your PHP code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email=$_POST["email"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
//do form validation here
$sql="SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE email='{$email}' AND password='{$password}'";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)==1) 
{
  $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
  $_SESSION["name"] =$row['email'];
  $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['user_name'];  
  $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['id']; 
  $_SESSION["login_status"] =TRUE;  
  header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $msg="Wrong Username and Password";
    header("Refresh:0");
   }   
}
}
```

If this help you please let me know.

Comment: My code is working fine on local host it accurately work on first time but when i upload to server then it take twice submit button with enter i also try your same code but im in same situation my problem is not resolved

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanAmjad this code is working correctly on my server. I suggest to check your server settings.